# What naming convention do I use for scripts in package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, naming-conventions, package.json

In `package.json` I have this script name with two words `lint` and `fix`. How should I make a right name?

There are options:

1. lowerCamelCase - `lintFix`
2. UpperCamelCase - `LintFix`
3. snake_case - `lint_fix`
4. kebab-case - `lint-fix`
5. gulp-style with a colon delimiter - `lint:fix`
6. Any another delimiter.

What option is right? And why?

Comment: Please see the link for more information: https://github.com/voorhoede/npm-style-guide

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no official naming convention. Before npm@v4 standard scripts had only one word, for example `test`, `start`, `prestart`. npm@v4 introduced a new script `prepublishOnly`*.

So now, the best practice is use **lowerCamelCase**.

*Reference: https://iamakulov.com/notes/npm-4-prepublish/

Comment: Any reference for this?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2kd0v71xto2mbaj/Screenshot%202019-12-31%2006.04.33.png?dl=0 `-` appears to be the 'norm' now. `:` for some select cases. As with most things in JS, this sort of thing can vary and is based on 'style guides' for organization/individual.

Answer (score 24):

Please ***always use kebab case***. The colon is a throwback to gulp, and it looks terrible. I hate it.

Disclaimer: My opinions are often wrong.

Answer (score 16):

Looking at npm itself, as in [galkin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45034125/1290368), seems like a good idea. But ironically, while the npm script `prepublishOnly` is lowerCamelCase, most scripts in the npm GitHub project are in kebab-case:
https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/latest/package.json.

One may also want to look at the most depended-on npm packages: https://www.npmjs.com/browse/depended. Many of the top packages there use kebab case, with the notable exception of lodash, which uses colons.

Update: There is also a convenience aspect which can matter more than one might think: it is more pleasant to type delimiters that don't need the shift key. At least on US, UK, and German keyboards, this too speaks for kebab-case.

Answer (score 11):

You can use a mix of both dash and colon. Dash for chaining words, colon for grouping similar scripts. Example:

- `lint:check`
- `lint:fix:all`
- `lint:fix:staged-only`